# mongodb find values in a date range but for specific times of day

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have a very simple mongodb database which has two important fields:

`date` and `value`

I have the following code to get readings from a specific date range. This query uses mongoose in node:

```
Reading.find({
  date: {
    $gte: startDate,
    $lte: endDate
  }
}).select('value date')
```

However I have a need to get readings at a specific time of day. I could do this on the frontend of my application but I believe it may be faster to do it on the database level.

How do I do something like this?

```
Reading.find({
  date: {
    $gte: startDate,
    $lte: endDate
  },
  $hour: {
    $gte: 18,
    $lte: 24
  }
}).select('value date')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) to use `$hour`, try:

```
Reading.find({
    $expr: {
        $and: [
            { $gte: [ "$date", startDate ] },
            { $lte: [ "$date", endDate ] },
            { $gte: [ { $hour: { $toDate: "$date" } }, 18 ] },
            { $lte: [ { $hour: { $toDate: "$date" } }, 23 ] }
        ]
    }
}).select('value date')
```

Please note that [$hour](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/hour/index.html) returns a value between `0` and `23` so `23` will be returned for `23:59`

Comment: Note, Date values are stored in UTC time. You may have to convert values to local times. (using `$dateToParts`) or use field `{ $hour: {date: "$date", timezone: "<your time zone>"} }`

Comment: I tried this out as it looks spot on, but I get `can't convert from BSON type long to Date`. I am not sure what would be triggering that?
I have `"date": 1579621683063` and `"dateString": "2020-01-21T15:48:03.063+0000"` available, both seem to cause that error.

Comment: @userqwert try to run $toDate on `dateString`, `$hour` can only be run on I`SODate`: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/

Comment: Like this? Im getting unrecognised $toDate

`Reading.find({
    $expr: {
      $and: [
        { $gte: ['$date', startDate] },
        { $lte: ['$date', endDate] },
        { $gte: [{ $hour: { $toDate: '$dateString' } }, 18] },
        { $lte: [{ $hour: { $toDate: '$dateString' } }, 23] }
      ]
    }`

Comment: I think mongoose doesn't support `$toDate` yet - do you know an another way to do that? Thanks for posting that playground it will be very helpful for me.

Comment: @userqwert what is your MongoDB version?

Comment: I am using mlab for hosting and "mongoose": "^5.8.9" on my server.

Comment: how about trying `$match`: https://mongoplayground.net/p/_MSyVIWKL8F ?

Comment: Managed to get this working with `$hour: { $dateFromString: { dateString: '$dateString' } }`. Thanks for helping out @mickl

Answer (score 1):

Actually your first query must work if you include time info in the startDate and endDate date variables.

You can set hours on these variables before the query, and it should work.

```js
  let startDate = new Date(2020, 2, 15); //months between 0-11, so 2 means March
  let endDate = new Date(2020, 2, 15);

  startDate.setHours(20);
  endDate.setHours(24);

  const result = await Reading.find({
    date: {
      $gte: startDate,
      $lte: endDate
    }
  }).select("value date");
```

Sample documents:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e6e37d0b530b737e04ba937"),
    "date" : ISODate("2020-03-15T23:11:56.443+03:00"),
    "value" : "value4"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e6e33b7be142a2bf0c8f75c"),
    "date" : ISODate("2020-03-15T21:54:15.823+03:00"),
    "value" : "value3"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e6e33b4be142a2bf0c8f75b"),
    "date" : ISODate("2020-03-15T19:54:15.823+03:00"),
    "value" : "value2"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e6e33b1be142a2bf0c8f75a"),
    "date" : ISODate("2020-03-15T17:54:15.823+03:00"),
    "value" : "value1"
}
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "date": "2020-03-15T18:54:15.823Z",
        "_id": "5e6e33b7be142a2bf0c8f75c",
        "value": "value3"
    },
    {
        "date": "2020-03-15T20:11:56.443Z",
        "_id": "5e6e37d0b530b737e04ba937",
        "value": "value4"
    }
]
```

I have +3 time zone, so 18:54 is actually 21:54, and 20:11 is 23:11.